# Подскажите где ошибка в query запросе mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{ 'results' : { $in: [ { $gte : 70}, { $lte : 80 } ] } }
```

Comment: Вроде бы, все верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ 'results' : {$gte : 70,  $lte : 80 }  }
```